# Devise::Models inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to understand more deeply Rails engines mechanisms, watching the sources of devise project.

You know, there is that module `Devise::Models` that defines a method called `devise` for models that will support authentication and stuff. All good so far.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models.rb

But it's hard to me to figure out how this module is included in the models. Is it autoloaded or something ? When I create a new model without using generators, how the hell devise makes accessible Devise::Models module so that I can directly call `devise :trackable, :stuffable`.

That's just dark to me. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: To give some further details, I am trying to make an engine and I would like to make a method like Devise's `devise :trackable, :rememberable` that would be available for the models of my host projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, I feel stupid. I spent so many hours to find out why `Devise::Models` module was included in all my models, and I could call `devise` method without raising a NoMethod error.

Finally I found the answer.

This module is included in the orm file that your devise installation uses. You do this stuff, if you didn't changed that, in your initializer. (Choosing the right Orm adapter file)

Then the file included in question (in my case, `mongoid.yml`) simply does :

```
require 'orm_adapter/adapters/mongoid'

Mongoid::Document::ClassMethods.send :include, Devise::Models
```

Hope this will inspire you if you will to provide same mechanism for your engine.

Regards